# Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'com.example.asus.vidasegura.SesionFragment', required: 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, programación-móvil

Me sale ese error al tratar de llamar a un fragment en android studio.

Continuación del error:

```
replace(int,android.support.v4.app.Fragment)
in FragmentTransaction cannot be applied to
(int, com.example.asus.vidasegura.SesionFragment)
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.asus.vidasegura;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.escenario, new SesionFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

SesionFragment.java

```
package com.example.asus.vidasegura;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;




public class SesionFragment extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sesion, container, false);
    }
}
```

El error me tira a `new SesionFragment()` en el MainActivity.java

A que se deberá este error? :(

Comment: Hay dos tipos de librerías para fragments: app.Fragment y support.v4.app.Fragment, así que en los import o usas una u otra en ambas clases

Comment: Lee linea por linea del codigo del `SesionFragment` hay una que dice `import android.app.Fragment` borra esa linea y pon esta: `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`. El error te sale en `MainActivity` porque utilizas una clase que no maneja ese tipo de `Fragment`. Te recomiendo un curso básico de Java antes de entrar de lleno a Android, se te va a hacer complejo si empiezas a programar directamente Android si no tienes una base en Java, especificamente POO.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que estas utilizando el [SupportFragmentManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager), que solo maneja los `Fragments` del paquete `android.support.v4.app`.

En tu `SesionFragment`, intenta importar:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

en vez de:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

Esto debes hacerlo con todos los demas `Fragments` que hayas creado, si vas a utilizar el `SupportFragmentManager` en la `Activity` que maneja tus `Fragments`.

Comment: Pero como, en SesionFragment tengo que importar las librerias?, es que lo hice pero no se me soluciona el error que me sale en MainActivity

Comment: en SessionFragment importa import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; elimina import android.app.Fragment;

Answer (score 0):

El error indica simplemente que para usar el método `replace(int,android.support.v4.app.Fragment)` necesitas un Fragment de la clase:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

y no de la clase

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

cambia el Import para que tu `Fragment` `SesionFragment` extienda de `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`:

```
package com.example.asus.vidasegura;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
//import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; //*Agrega!
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;




public class SesionFragment extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sesion, container, false);
    }
}
```